# Complex Lucene queries in ElasticSearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, lucene

We've been using Lucene for the last years and we are about to migrate to ElasticSearch. We have lot of Lucene queries (complex ones) that we want to reuse. I've seen in ElasticSearch the "query_string" API (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#query-string-syntax). It works pretty good for simple queries, but it doesn't when using functions like *spanNear* or *spanOr*. See below a part of a query:

```
spanNear([spanOr([ADDRESS:13, ADDRESS:13a, ADDRESS:13b, ADDRESS:13c, ADDRESS:13d, ADDRESS:13e, ADDRESS:13f, ADDRESS:13g, ADDRESS:13h, ADDRESS:13i, ADDRESS:13j, ADDRESS:13k, ADDRESS:13l, ADDRESS:13m, ADDRESS:13n, ADDRESS:13r, ADDRESS:13s, ADDRESS:13u, ADDRESS:13v, ADDRESS:13w, ADDRESS:13x, ADDRESS:13y, ADDRESS:13z]), [ADDRESS:carlton, ADDRESS:chalton, ADDRESS:charaton, ADDRESS:charleton, ADDRESS:charlon, ADDRESS:charlson, ADDRESS:charlston, ADDRESS:charlton, ADDRESS:charltons, ADDRESS:charlvon, ADDRESS:charston, ADDRESS:charton, ADDRESS:chorlton, ADDRESS:harlton, ADDRESS:sharlton]))
```

Do you know which is the best way of using these kind of queries without rewriting them into ES format? We use the Lucene Java libraries for generating the queries in case it helps. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are looking for. So, you are generating `SpanNearQuery` and `SpanOrQuery` in java, and want to use the same queries in ElasticSearch without rewriting them? Presumably you don't mean you want to pass *java code* into the ElasticSearch API, so what do you mean when you say you don't want to rewrite them?

Comment: @femtoRgon Since ElasticSearch allows passing Lucene queries with the query_string API, I just get the native Lucene query I was generating. When I do so, that is the output I get, with the spanNear and spanOr functions. If I send that query to ElasticSearch it does not find spanNear or spanOr...

Comment: Do you mean you are just getting the `toString` from your query? There is nothing in Elasticsearch (or Lucene, for that matter) which will parse the output of Query.toString.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are getting the `toString` from your query, and hoping the ElasticSearch will parse it. Bad news, there is nothing in Elasticsearch which will parse the output of `Query.toString`. There is also nothing in Lucene that will parse it. For simple queries it *may* spit out a parseable query string, but that is never guaranteed. `Query.toString()` is for debugging, not serializing.

To run these queries in elasticsearch, the API supports the full compliment of [span queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/span-queries.html), including [span_near](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-near-query.html) and [span_or](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-span-or-query.html)

There are also query parsers which do have syntax supporting span queries such as [Surround](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/surround/parser/QueryParser.html) and [Complex Phrase](https://lucene.apache.org/core/7_0_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/complexPhrase/ComplexPhraseQueryParser.html). ElasticSearch doesn't have them out of the box, though, but could be an option if you are willing to do the leg work to put together a plugin to use them in ElasticSearch (a process I've seen references to, and it looks quite manageable, but which I am not really familiar with).

Comment: Thanks for the answer... Query.toString() returns the string representation of the Lucene query, but it includes the spanNear spanOr functions... I will take a look at Surround and Complex Phrase.

Comment: I feel I should reiterate, toString does *not* serialize the query. The results of the ToString method are for human consumption (this is true of [java, in general](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29), not just lucene queries). The "spanNear" and "spanOr" you are seeing are not functions, they are *human-readable debugging output*. Surround and Complex Phrase are parsers that have features you may find useful, but neither of them are going to parse that string, either.